# How to send data to fake server json

Tags: angular

I'm setting up an application with angular 7 (Frontend) and with fake server json (backend), and i want to send user's details ( Firstname , Role , LoginTime , duration of connection ) to my fake server json ! But it does not work ! The server json is always empty !

details.ts :

```
import {AuthenticationService} from '../_services';
import { User } from '../_models';
export class Details 
{ 
authenticationService : AuthenticationService;

currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;

role = this.currentUser.role;
logintime = this.authenticationService.today;
duree = this.authenticationService.timeLeft;

}
```

details.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Employee } from '../shared/employee';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Details} from './details';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DetailsService  {
apiURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})
 }  


createEmployee(details): Observable<Details> {
return this.http.post<Details>(this.apiURL + '/details', 
JSON.stringify(details), this.httpOptions)
.pipe(
  retry(1),
  catchError(this.handleError)
)
}

getEmployees(): Observable<Details> {
return this.http.get<Details>(this.apiURL + '/details')
.pipe(
  retry(1),
  catchError(this.handleError)
)
}

handleError(error) {
let errorMessage = '';
if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
  // Get client-side error
  errorMessage = error.error.message;
} else {
  // Get server-side error
  errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: 
${error.message}`;
}
window.alert(errorMessage);
return throwError(errorMessage);
}

}
```

I expect to see user's details in the fake json server but it is empty ! Thanks for help

Comment: What is the `fake server` ?

Comment: @AJT_82 check this link https://medium.com/@siddharthamajumdar/how-to-create-a-fake-server-using-json-server-84a2eefb5095

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is fake server returns user data from http://localhost:3000/details

If your servers sends a data like this.

```
{
name:'some name',
role:'admin'
}
```

you can create a Details like

```
export class Details{
name:string;
role:string
}
```

You can consume like

```
this.detailsService.getEmployees().subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```